# Button with Image and a label on bottom

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit, interface-builder

I want to make a button which has an icon and a label on the bottom of it so like this:

[image]

What would be the best way to do this? Is it possible to drag an image view object and a label into a button?

Comment: I don't know where to start I tried adding a button but its' text is vertically centered so I don't know how to add an image on top of it. I'm new to swift so I really ain't so familiar with the objects sorry.

Comment: You don't know where to start?  How about whether this is an `NSButton` for OSX or a `UIButton` for iOS?  How about whether you're using interface builder or if you must do this programmatically?  And have you literally tried nothing so far?

Comment: It's an UIButton for iOS sorry forgot to mention that. I could add a view object and put an image view and label object to it would that be proper?

Comment: I know it could work that way but I just want to know the way it's supposed to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UIButton** has two properties you may find of interest. They are **titleEdgeInsets** and **imageEdgeInsets**.

> Use this property to resize and reposition the effective drawing rectangle for the button title. You can specify a different value for each of the four insets (top, left, bottom, right). A positive value shrinks, or insets, that edge—moving it closer to the center of the button. A negative value expands, or outsets, that edge

You could play around with these to get your desired layout.

Comment: Thank you! I am trying the collection view object is that an option too?

Comment: IMO if a stand-alone button is what you require then UIButton is the best choice, because it comes with a label and image with settings for different states. And as my answer states you can change the position of these to suit, however.. if you want a collection of buttons then a UICollectionView would be best but you'll need all the plumbing to go with it.(cells, layout, datasource, delegate, controller etc.) It all depends on the context of what it is intended. You could subclass UIView and code it up from scratch. There are many options, some are more time consuming than others.

Comment: You are right UICollectionView is more trouble than I expected I will look up more information on title and imageEdgeInsets and give that a try thank you.

Answer (score 11):

By code you can do it like this Swift 4.2 compatible code is here , you just need to call function

```
  public extension UIButton
  {

    func alignTextBelow(spacing: CGFloat = 6.0)
    {
        if let image = self.imageView?.image
        {
            let imageSize: CGSize = image.size
            self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: spacing, left: -imageSize.width, bottom: -(imageSize.height), right: 0.0)
            let labelString = NSString(string: self.titleLabel!.text!)
            let titleSize = labelString.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: self.titleLabel!.font])
            self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -(titleSize.height + spacing), left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: -titleSize.width)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: good answer. Worked in Swift 5.5

Answer (score 4):

Cleaned up @Shahzaib Maqbool's answer. I had some crashes originally, fixed those by removing the force unwrapping. Tested on Swift 5.

```
extension UIButton {
    func alignTextBelow(spacing: CGFloat = 6.0) {
        guard let image = self.imageView?.image else {
            return
        }

        guard let titleLabel = self.titleLabel else {
            return
        }

        guard let titleText = titleLabel.text else {
            return
        }

        let titleSize = titleText.size(withAttributes: [
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: titleLabel.font
        ])

        titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: spacing, left: -image.size.width, bottom: -image.size.height, right: 0)
        imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -(titleSize.height + spacing), left: 0, bottom: 0, right: -titleSize.width)
    }
}
```